# Scala collection whose elements can construct sibling instances using named parameters and default values?

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to have a collection of objects, each object a companion of a different class, which classes all share a common method defined in a superclass that can be invoked when looping through the collection with a `foreach()`.  I want the constructors of these sibling-classes to have the same named parameters *and default parameter values* as each other.  Finally, I want to minimize repeated code.

Thus far, I am trying to do this with case classes, since--if it worked--it would eliminate all the duplicated code of the companion-objects for each type.  The problem is that if I put all these companion objects into a `Set`, when I take them out again I lose the default parameters and parameter names.

Here is some example code of what I am describing:

```
trait MyType {
  val param: String
  def label = param   // all instances of all subclasses have this method
}

case class caseOne(override val param: String = "default") extends MyType
case class caseTwo(override val param: String = "default") extends MyType

object Main extends App {
  // I can construct instances using the companion objects' `apply()` method:
  val works1 = caseOne(param = "I have been explicitly set").label
  // I can construct instances that have the default parameter value
  val works2 = caseOne().label

  // But what I want to do is something like this:
  val set = Set(caseOne, caseTwo)
  for {
    companion <- set
  } {
    val fail1 = companion()                      // Fails to compile--not enough arguments
    val fail2 = companion(param = "not default") // Fails also as param has lost its name
    val succeeds = companion("nameless param")   // this works but not what I want
    println(fail1.label + fail2.label)           // this line is my goal
  }
}
```

Notably if the `Set` has only one element, then it compiles, suggesting the inferred type of the multi-element `Set` lacks the parameter name--even though they are the same--and the default values.  Also suggesting that if I gave the `Set` the right type parameter this could work.  But what would that type be?  Not `MyType` since that is the type of the companion classes rather that the objects in the `Set`.

I could define the companion objects explicitly, but that is the repeated code I want to avoid.

How can I loop through my collection, constructing instances of `MyType` subclasses on each iteration, with constructors that have my desired parameter names and default values?  All while minimizing repeated code?

**Update:** Originally the example code showed `caseOne` and `caseTwo` as having different default values for `param`.  That was incorrect; they are now the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to get exactly what you want since you don't really have much control over the auto-generated companion objects.  In particular for this to work they would all need to extend a common trait.  This is why it fails to compile when the set has more than one companion object; even though they all have a method with the same signature, they don't extend a common trait for the compiler to utilize.

You can use a nested case class and get something very similar though:

```
trait MyType {
  val param: String
  def label = param   // all instances of all subclasses have this method
}

abstract class MyTypeHelper(default: String) {

  case class Case(param: String) extends MyType

  def apply(param: String) : Case = Case(param)
  def apply(): Case = apply(default)
}

object One extends MyTypeHelper("default one")
object Two extends MyTypeHelper("default two")

object Example {

  val works1 = One(param = "I have been explicitly set").label
  val works2 = One().label

  val set = Set(One, Two)
  for {
    companion <- set
  } {
    val a = companion()                      
    val b = companion(param = "not default") 
    val c = companion("nameless param")   
    println(a.label + b.label)           
  }
}
```

Instead of having a `caseOne` type, you have `One.Case`, but it still implements `MyType` so you shouldn't have any issue anywhere else in the code that uses that trait.

Comment: That looks like it, thank you! Note: I made an error in the original example code: the two case classes should (and now do) have the same default value. Because I that I was able to use your `MyTypeHelper` with a single `apply()` method that defines the default value and I removed the `default` parameter from the `MyTypeHelper` constructor. I also changed `Case` from being a case class to a regular class--saving one character.  You unstuck me; many thanks again!